# Error when I compile on ubuntu

Tags: boost, ubuntu-16.04

Please help me I tried so much!

I've got a vps on ubuntu 16.04 and since a few weeks when I compile a daeomon I get this error:

```
libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-utiltime.o): In function `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::duration<long, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:252: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::hidden::sleep_for(timespec const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2763: recipe for target  failed
```

I tried to purge boost and reinstall but this error keeps coming, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: So, what is the content of line `2763` of your (?) `Makefile`?

Comment: Report it to the maintainers. It probably means they forgot to link `libboost_thread.so`

Comment: Which daemon? What Makefile? Errors like this are too generic, yet very environment dependent. I'd suggest asking the writer/maintainer of the software about this.

Comment: it happens with every daemon sadly : /